# Intel UHD770 not working on ubuntu20.04with kernel 5.19.0

Tags: drivers, kernel, graphics

I recently assembled a 13700k computer. After installing ubuntu22.04 (kernel 5.19), I can correctly identify the integrated graphics card uhd770.
However, due to work needs, only ubuntu20 can be used, so I compiled and installed the 5.19 kernel on ubuntu20, the process is as follows:

tar -xavf linux-5.19.tar.xz

cd linux-5.19

sudo make mrproper

sudo make clean

make menuconfig

sudo make -j16

sudo make modules_install -j16

sudo make install

sudo update-initramfs -c -k 5.19.0

sudo update-grub

sudo reboot

But after restarting, it was found that the graphics card still displayed llvmpipe (the uhd770 integrated graphics card was not recognized)

Excuse me, why the graphics card is still not recognized after updating the kernel

Comment: Please clarify your details; you mention 20.04 with the 5.19 kernel?  (5.15 is the HWE kernel for 20.04 & 5.4 the GA kernel)... so are you using 20.04?  20 & 20.04 are different systems (20 being *snap* only version of 20.04) and you also mention 22.04 - so check & clarify your details.  Ubuntu 20.04 LTS & Ubuntu 22.04 LTS share a kernel so have you tried that?  (ie. HWE stack of 20.04 is the GA stack of 22.04?)  As LTS releases have kernel stack options!  I'd for sure try a *supported* kernel rather than say 5.19 that is in it's last days of *supported* life security wise!

Comment: 1. I first installed ubuntu22.04.2LTS, and used uname -a to confirm that it is the 5.19 kernel, and this version can correctly identify my uhd770;
2. So then I installed ubuntu20.04.6LTS, he used the 5.15 kernel, and I confirmed that the kernel 5.19 has a uhd770 driver inside, so I upgraded to the 5.19 kernel on ubuntu20.04.6LTS.  so I can recompile and install the 5.19 kernel, but I find that uhd770 is still not recognized after installation. Please let me know if my description is detailed.